# Getting "Divide by zero error encountered" error while running the below query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, casting, common-table-expression

I am not sure about the error as I am trying to run this query. It is giving me the Divide by zero error. this error occurs at line 1.

```
Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Divide by zero error encountered.
```

could anyone please help?

```
SELECT temp1.*,90  as Plan_val,max(cast(Round(temp2.actual,0) as int))  as actual_val FROM(
SELECT t.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)],t.[Problem_Type_Name(Child)] , REPORT_DATE, CLOSE_DATE,[Assigned Tech],NAME , Job_ticket_id FROM (
SELECT 'NOC Incident Resolution - High' as [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)],[Problem_Type_Name(Child)] , REPORT_DATE, CLOSE_DATE,[Assigned Tech],NAME , Job_ticket_id
FROM TEMP_TICKET_STATE

UNION

SELECT 'NOC Incident Resolution - High' as [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)],[Problem_Type_Name(Child)] , REPORT_DATE, CLOSE_DATE,[Assigned Tech],NAME , Job_ticket_id
FROM TEMP_TICKET_STATE
where  [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)]='Incident (Technical Issues)'  and PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME  in ('High') AND (ISNULL([Escalated to Closed time],0) <= 120 or ISNULL([Escalated to Resolved time],0) <=120)) t

group by t.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)] ,t.[Problem_Type_Name(Child)] , REPORT_DATE, CLOSE_DATE,[Assigned Tech],NAME , Job_ticket_id) temp1

INNER JOIN

(
SELECT t.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)],t.[Problem_Type_Name(Child)],0 AS plan_val, cast(Round((cast(sum(t.Total_tickets) as decimal(38,2))- cast(sum(t.Alarm_Val) as decimal(38,2)))/cast(sum(t.Total_tickets) as decimal(38,2))*100,0) as int) as actual  FROM (
SELECT 'NOC Incident Resolution - High' as [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)] ,[Problem_Type_Name(Child)],0 as Alarm_Val, cast (count(distinct [Job_ticket_id])/4 as int) as Total_tickets 
FROM TEMP_TICKET_STATE_month
group by [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)] ,[Problem_Type_Name(Child)] 

UNION

SELECT 'NOC Incident Resolution - High' as [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)] ,[Problem_Type_Name(Child)],cast (count(distinct [Job_ticket_id])/4 as int) as Alarm_Val, 0 as Total_tickets 
FROM TEMP_TICKET_STATE_month
where  [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)]='Incident (Technical Issues)'  and PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME  in ('High') AND (ISNULL([Escalated to Closed time],0) <= 120 or ISNULL([Escalated to Resolved time],0) <=120)
group by [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)] ,[Problem_Type_Name(Child)] ) t

group by t.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)],t.[Problem_Type_Name(Child)]) temp2

ON temp1.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)]=temp2.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)]
Group by temp1.[Assigned Tech],temp1.Close_Date,temp1.Job_ticket_id,temp1.NAME,temp1.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)],temp1.[Problem_Type_Name(Child)] ,temp1.Report_Date

GO
```

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question

Comment: This is impossible to answer without actual data. But, you have number of divisions that happen, so that's where the issue is going. Try to make a CASE statement where if the denominator is 0, then output NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one quotient that can be failing - there are 3 divisions in the query, and 2 divide by constants. Try this:

```
SELECT temp1.*,90  as Plan_val,max(cast(Round(temp2.actual,0) as int))  as actual_val FROM(
SELECT t.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)],t.[Problem_Type_Name(Child)] , REPORT_DATE, CLOSE_DATE,[Assigned Tech],NAME , Job_ticket_id FROM (
SELECT 'NOC Incident Resolution - High' as [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)],[Problem_Type_Name(Child)] , REPORT_DATE, CLOSE_DATE,[Assigned Tech],NAME , Job_ticket_id
FROM TEMP_TICKET_STATE

UNION

SELECT 'NOC Incident Resolution - High' as [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)],[Problem_Type_Name(Child)] , REPORT_DATE, CLOSE_DATE,[Assigned Tech],NAME , Job_ticket_id
FROM TEMP_TICKET_STATE
where  [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)]='Incident (Technical Issues)'  and PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME  in ('High') AND (ISNULL([Escalated to Closed time],0) <= 120 or ISNULL([Escalated to Resolved time],0) <=120)) t

group by t.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)] ,t.[Problem_Type_Name(Child)] , REPORT_DATE, CLOSE_DATE,[Assigned Tech],NAME , Job_ticket_id) temp1

INNER JOIN

(
SELECT t.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)],t.[Problem_Type_Name(Child)],0 AS plan_val, 
    -- CHANGE IS THE CASE ON THE NEXT LINE!
    case when sum(t.Total_tickets) = 0 then null else cast(Round((cast(sum(t.Total_tickets) as decimal(38,2))- cast(sum(t.Alarm_Val) as decimal(38,2)))/cast(sum(t.Total_tickets) as decimal(38,2))*100,0) as int) end as actual  FROM (
SELECT 'NOC Incident Resolution - High' as [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)] ,[Problem_Type_Name(Child)],0 as Alarm_Val, cast (count(distinct [Job_ticket_id])/4 as int) as Total_tickets 
FROM TEMP_TICKET_STATE_month
group by [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)] ,[Problem_Type_Name(Child)] 

UNION

SELECT 'NOC Incident Resolution - High' as [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)] ,[Problem_Type_Name(Child)],cast (count(distinct [Job_ticket_id])/4 as int) as Alarm_Val, 0 as Total_tickets 
FROM TEMP_TICKET_STATE_month
where  [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)]='Incident (Technical Issues)'  and PRIORITY_TYPE_NAME  in ('High') AND (ISNULL([Escalated to Closed time],0) <= 120 or ISNULL([Escalated to Resolved time],0) <=120)
group by [Problem_Type_Name(Parent)] ,[Problem_Type_Name(Child)] ) t

group by t.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)],t.[Problem_Type_Name(Child)]) temp2

ON temp1.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)]=temp2.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)]
Group by temp1.[Assigned Tech],temp1.Close_Date,temp1.Job_ticket_id,temp1.NAME,temp1.[Problem_Type_Name(Parent)],temp1.[Problem_Type_Name(Child)] ,temp1.Report_Date

GO
```

Comment: this gave me the following error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 30
Incorrect syntax near 'temp2'.

Comment: @SankW - sorry, and one more edit still... A couple lines got chopped off the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, there is the only one denominator which could be zero.  The others appear to be a constant 4.

One simple technique for trapping the dreaded **Divide By Zero** is **NullIf()**.

For example `NullIf(<any denominator>,0)`  this will return NULL if the denominator = 0

So in your case:

```
NullIf(cast(sum(t.Total_tickets) as decimal(38,2)),0)
```

Comment: @SankW Happy it helped